# Add conjunction to grammar rule - NLTK parse into syntax tree in python

Tags: python, parsing, nltk

Suppose  we  have following incomplete  grammar rule:

```
grammar2 = nltk.parse_cfg("""
S -> NP VP
NP -> Det N
VP -> V NP
PN -> 'David' 
Det -> 'the'
N -> 'man' 
V -> 'saw' | 'helped' 
Pro -> 'him'
Conj -> 'and'
""")
```

I want to create syntax tree for following sentence:

```
sent = ['the', 'man', 'saw', 'David', 'and', 'helped', 'him']
parser = nltk.ChartParser(grammar2)
trees = parser.nbest_parse(sent)
for tree in trees:
    print tree
```

But I don't know how can I add conjunction `and` in the grammar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A job for recursion. This should work.

```
S -> NP VP 
VP -> V NP | V NP Conj VP
NP -> Det N | PN | Pro
PN -> 'David' 
Det -> 'the'
N -> 'man' 
V -> 'saw' | 'helped' 
Pro -> 'him'
Conj -> 'and'
```

Comment: But I think we should  write it as `S conj S`. or I am mistake?

Comment: You don't. S Conj S is even more accurate in a linguistic sense because of the two finite verb phrases. But in that case the second sentence comes along with a subject gap. That is,

Comment: suppose there is no subject gap, could you please tell me how can I parse this sentence: `sent = ['the', 'man', 'saw', 'David', 'and', 'he','helped', 'him']` as `S Conj S`

Comment: Ok, this should cover both the example with and without subject gap: `S -> NP VP | VP | NP VP Conj S`. The shortcoming is that S can have a NP or not. That is a little lame. You can consider defining symbols for different kinds of sentence, i.e. CS for conjunction sentence or GS for gap sentence and so on.